# Android support design spinner

Tags: android

I used android support design for edit text.

How can I use it for spinner (material design).

Like this (Product Category).

[image: product cat]

That spinner is well aligned with the edit text.
I need something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```